# django send_mail 554 - relay access denied

Tags: python, django, email

I googled a lot about this problem, and i found this error in a plenty of locations, but no answer for my problem.

I' ve a newly installed (debian) system, which contains basically only a django (1.3.0) installation, and a very poor postfix. Postfix is working, if i do

```
echo sth | mail somebody@provider.com
```

it arrives perfectly.

I tried to use django send_mail like

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('aaa', 'bbb', 'from@localhost', ['user@external.hu'])
```

but I get back always an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 61, in send_mail
    connection=connection).send()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 248, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 92, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 110, in _send
    email_message.message().as_string())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 709, in sendmail
    raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'user@external.hu': (554, '5.7.1 : Relay access denied')}
```

Certainly I tried with different addresses. The only one cases when he delivers the email is the one, when I send it to `localhost` (or to hosts having mx on this machine).

In the `mail.log` I can see this:

```
Apr 16 10:48:48 tkt postfix/smtpd[4886]: connect from tkt[217.112.142.235]
Apr 16 10:48:48 tkt postfix/smtpd[4886]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from tkt[217.112.142.235]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=ESMTP helo=
Apr 16 10:48:48 tkt postfix/smtpd[4882]: lost connection after RSET from tkt[217.112.142.235]
Apr 16 10:48:48 tkt postfix/smtpd[4882]: disconnect from tkt[217.112.142.235]
```

Sniffing port 25 I can see nothing.

Anyone any idea how to solve this problem (using the local postfix most prefereably)?

The machine is on the Internet site, and as I wrote, mail sending works ok from command line.

Comment: Can you try the from email not to send from the localhost like localhost.com or something. It looks like that you server this not allowed

Comment: Hi, sure, as i said i tried with plenty of combinations, but unfortunately it' s the same (send_mail('aaa', 'bbb', 'alma@yahoo.com', ['beka@gmail.com'])) .

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the difference between...

```
echo sth | mail somebody@provider.com
```

...and...

```
send_mail('aaa', 'bbb', 'from@localhost', ['user@external.hu'])
```

...is that the former is connecting to postfix on IP address `127.0.0.1`, but the latter is connecting to postfix on IP address `217.112.142.235`, although I'm not sure why. It might depend on which IP address your webserver is bound to.

Postfix is typically configured by default to only allow email to be relayed when connected to on `127.0.0.1` for security reasons.

You can either change your Django `settings.py` to force it to use `127.0.0.1` by adding...

```
EMAIL_HOST='localhost'
```

...or reconfigure postfix to allow relaying from `217.112.142.235` by changing the `mynetworks` param in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` from something like...

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
```

...to something list...

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 217.112.142.235/32
```

...then do...

```
sudo service postfix restart
```

...to make it re-read the confing.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Basically i had an entry for <code>EMAIL_HOST</conde> in the settings. and that caused the whole problem ... . After just simply removing it, it works fine.

Comment: @user2194805 It's customary to accept an answer if it's helped solve your problem so that people can easily tell the problem has been solved.